# Require all boxes on form be checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get a form to require that all checkboxes be checked to indicate the person has read all of the sections before allowing submission.  The html is like

```js
     function checkform()
    {
 if (!this.rsa.secOne.checked)
 {
 
  alert('All boxes must be checked');
  return false;
 }
 else if (!this.rsa.secTwo.checked)
 {
 
  alert('All boxes must be checked');
  return false;
 }
      else if (!this.rsa.secThree.checked)
 {
  alert('All boxes must be checked');
  return false;
 }

 return true;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
      <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Exhibit C</title>
      </head>
      <body>
           <form action="rsaOne.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" id="rsa" name="rsa">
              <input type="checkbox" id="secOne" name="secOne"><b>SECTION 1. </b><u>
```

I get checkform is not defined.  How can I change this to make it work?  There are 23 checkboxes total, I can copy the else if over and over and change the identifier, if someone can just tell me what to change to make this much work.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `required`:

Just add a `required` attribute to each input element like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="secOne" name="secOne" required>
<input type="checkbox" id="secTwo" name="secTwo" required>
```

### Using `HTMLFormElement.elements` to dynamically set `required` attribute with JavaScript:

If there are too many checkboses and/or you want to dynamically use JavaScript to add the `required` attribute to all your checkboxes, you can just use the **[HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)** property to get all the form controls (here, your checkboxes) inside your form and then use the **[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** method to get a shallow-copied array of the *HTMLFormControlsCollection* which you can now loop over and use the **[setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** method to dynamically set a `required` attribute to all the checkboxes.

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/vey9un4w/5/)** link for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
// get the form
const form = document.getElementById("rsa");

// get the form controls
let x = form.elements;

// Convert the list of form controls to an array and set the required attribute to each control
Array.from(x).forEach(e => {
 e.setAttribute("required", ""); 
})
```

```html
<form action="rsaOne.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" id="rsa" name="rsa">
    <input type="checkbox" id="secOne" name="secOne" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secTwo" name="secTwo" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secThree" name="secThree" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secFour" name="secFour" required>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function checkForm() {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(".reqCheck")].every(el => el.checked)
}
```

Formatted for testing purposes:

```js
function checkForm() {
  const allChecked = [...document.querySelectorAll(".reqCheck")].every(el => el.checked)
  console.log(allChecked)
  return allChecked
}
```

```html
<form action="rsaOne.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()" id="rsa" name="rsa">
  <input type="checkbox" class="reqCheck" name="secOne" id="secOne">
  <label for="secOne"> SECTION 1.</label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="reqCheck" name="secTwo" id="secTwo">
  <label for="secTwo">SECTION 2.</label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="reqCheck" name="secThree" id="secThree">
  <label for="secThree"> SECTION 3.</label><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because you put `checkForm()` with a capital F on the onSubmit callback but when you created the function it is `checkform()`.

Just change `checkForm()` to `checkform()`